# Как работает getText() в java

Tags: java

Узнал, что можно в `JFrame` заменить `Scanner` на `getText()`, но не знаю как он работает.

К примеру мне надо, чтобы в `int d;` записывалось значение написанное  в  моём 
`JTextField burl`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
@FXML private TextField file;
@FXML
protected void file() throws Exception {
    (label_text = new Label()).setText(file.getText());
}
```

main.fxml

```
<TextField fx:id="file" ... onAction="#file" />
```

Вот вам пример использования этой функции, считывание данных String из блока TextField. Акшоны можете проставить любые от конечного заполнения символа, до нажатия кнопки, чтобы параметр был записан в label_text,  используйте уже его от туда.

Answer (score 1):

Да, все верно, вы можете заменить на `getText()` - считывает строку из `jTextField` и преобразовывает её в числовой формат:

```
Integer d = Integer.parseInt(burl.getText())
```

---

Пример её использования при нажатии на кнопку `JButton click`:

```
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Integer d = Integer.parseInt(burl.getText());
    }
});
```